# Blocking xlargescreens does not work even after changing targetSDK

Tags: android, android-market-filtering

I am developing an app for handsets. I want to block xlargeScreens, but that is only avalible for SDK level 9 or higher and I am developing for 7. I have tried solving this with this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

But I still get the same error that it do not find the resource. How can I fix this? (I have read all similar questions with no luck. Please do not send links.)

Comment: chose android build target level 9 in `eclipse`

Comment: I go Properties/Android/BuildTarget 10/Ok and it is still not working and it still gives the same error

Comment: what is not working? It still gives error?

Comment: For some reason it worked after adding an element around it and then remove it. Strange :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to block xlargeScreens

You can't, using `<supports-screens>`. You can only block `-xlarge` using `<compatible-screens>`.

Comment: I did not know. Thanks @CommonsWare!